# Connect printer to server and avoid clients to map it directly

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, printing

How can I connect a printer to my server. So clients cant connect to it directly ?

I tried add another etnernetcard and give it a other static ip but that just work wierd when im and my server give me a yellow icon that there is no internet connection.

windows 2012 server

And its a TCP/ip printer

I want to connect it to my server and share it that way with permissions

Comment: Please give us more details. What is your printer type? What is your server OS?

Comment: You're going to need to do better than "that just work wierd" if you want help troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can set some access control list on your printer, or you need to firewall it somehow, or move it to another subnet, or even directly connect it to your server. All of those options work, and highly depend on your infrastructure.